# How to recover data from overwritten NTFS partition?

Tags: data-recovery

curious situation here. NTFS partition on my SSD (with Win8) got corrupted and became unbootable and inaccessible even if connected the drive into a different computer.

However when I deleted the partition in Disk Manager and created new NTFS in it's place, all seems to be fine. The new partition is accessible, readable and writable. So what I thought was a failed SSD turned out to be broken partition.

The question is? Can I get my data back?

Comment: http://superuser.com/search?q=recover+data+SSD

Comment: A partition can't become broken. Your should use the statement "corrupted partition table" but healthy drives don't have corrupted partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly. Try not to use your SSD if at all possible during the meantime - if you do, you *could* lose some data permanently.

There's a utility called TestDisk that you can use to scan for deleted partitions, but reading is required. You can download it and read how-to guides for it at http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk.

Again, don't attempt using your SSD. If it's at all possible to put it in another machine or boot off of another disk with an alternate OS, do so.